# ab is erroring out with apr_socket_recv: Connection refused (61)

Tags: apachebench

I am testing eventlet out, and I am getting this error:

```
~>ab -n 10 -c 1 http://localhost:8090/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)...apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (54)
Total of 2 requests completed
```

The website works at localhost:8090/ and returns 200 OK.

I had the same issue with tomcat, again the website worked fine.

What could the issue be?

Comment: Could this be an ipv6 problem, ab trying to translate localhost and use ::1 first and failing?

Comment: Could this be a firewall problem? Or maybe you are using proxy?

Comment: If you get this error when `ab` has made ~16k requests, on macOS, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30357879/537554 for an explanation, and https://serverfault.com/a/145937/91715 for a fix.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

I found using 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost worked:

`ab -n 10 -c 1 http://127.0.0.1:8090/`

Update:
May have been a bug in ab: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nodejs/TZU5H7MdoII/yivu0d4LMaAJ

Comment: hi, not for me, I get the same error.  Are you running lion?  it worked fine for me b4 upgrading.

Comment: My error was slightly different to you - but yes I'm on Lion. Looks like an ab bug on Lion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nodejs/TZU5H7MdoII/yivu0d4LMaAJ

Comment: Same goes for Mountain Lion, it has version 2.3 of ab.

Comment: my be reduce the concurrency parameter which worked for me

Answer (score 11):

New versions of Apache have fixed the issue. Download the latest package from https://archive.apache.org/dist/:

```
$ wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/httpd-2.3.16-beta.tar.bz2
$ tar jxvf httpd-2.3.16-beta.tar.bz2 
$ cd httpd-2.3.16-beta
$ ./configure
```

You only have to build ab, which is located in the `support` folder.

```
$ cd support
$ make
...
$ ./ab -n 10 -c 1 http://localhost:8090/
```

Comment: Make sure to cp support/ab to /usr/sbin (or wherever as determined by 'which ab'

Comment: This links to a page for RTFM; frankly the user that added that link, should be banned

Comment: @MrMesees: It’s just a dead link that used to be a patch file back in 2012 when this answer was written.

Answer (score 10):

add the `-r` option which means  Don't exit on socket receive errors.
At times you might change the default ulimit size value.

`ab -r -n 10 -c 1 http://localhost:8090/`

Answer (score 1):

Another [related bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61968) that is still present in `ab` (`apache-2.4.29`) is that it takes just the first result from `getaddrinfo`. It's probably this bug that is mentioned by  Jürgen Strobel in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938869/ab-is-erroring-out-with-apr-socket-recv-connection-refused-61#comment9961596_7938869). Let's say you have `/etc/hosts` that goes like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1     localhost.localdomain   localhost
```

The first result  returned by `getaddrinfo` for `localhost` is `::1`. So `ab` tries to connect over IPv6 and fails. The workaround is to use `127.0.0.1`: `ab -n 10 127.0.0.1/`. Or reorder the lines. Though, in my case it says:

```
Benchmarking localhost (be patient)...apr_socket_recv: Connection refused (111)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch for this bug, I followed the steps of [this guide](http://forrst.com/posts/Fixing_ApacheBench_bug_on_Mac_OS_X_Lion-wku) and it seems to work for me now in Lion.