# ab (Apache Bench) error: apr_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007) on Windows

Tags: apachebench

I'm load testing IIS 7.5 (WinR2/SP1) from my Windows 7/SP1 client. I have a script that makes three `ab` calls like:

```
start /B cmd /c ab.exe -k -n 500 -c 50 http://rhvwr2vsu410/HelloWebAPI/Home/SyncProducts > SyncProducts.txt
```

When the concurrency is > 5, I soon get the error message

```
apr_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
```

And `ab` stops making requests. I don't even get to *Completed 100 requests*.

This happens within 30 seconds of starting my script. The [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) documentation page doesn't provide much. [Related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156537/why-does-a-simple-thin-server-stop-responding-at-16500-requests-when-benchmarkin). [Server Fault related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/10852/what-limits-the-maximum-number-of-connections-on-a-linux-server) .

Comment: A similar thing happened to me as well. The problem was related to my code. Not sure if this is the case here, though.

Comment: @tugberk - exactly, a bug in my WebApi code limited concurrency. As soon as I fixed the bug the apr_poll message went away.

Comment: You can try the solution given in this thread: http://serverfault.com/questions/10852/what-limits-the-maximum-number-of-connections-on-a-linux-server

Comment: I think this question is old, but I am still getting this problem from the command line, e.g. `ab http://myinternalserver.tld/file.txt` but it works when I add `-X 127.0.0.1:8888` to go through my local debug proxy and it works using curl. Any clues?

Answer (score 34):

You must have the 2.4 version and use [`-s timeout` option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html).

Edit:

https://www.wampserver.com/ - includes Apache 2.4.x Win32 and Win64.

Deprecated <strike>but still available however I not known until when</strike> and just not available:

You can use my win32-x86 binary (compiled under Visual Studio 2008 from trunk 8 Feb 2013):

- <strike>http://mars.iti.pk.edu.pl/~nkg/ab-standalone.exe</strike> (no longer available)
- <strike>http://mars.iti.pk.edu.pl/~nkg/ab-standalone-src.zip</strike> (no longer available)

I was made it using: http://code.google.com/p/apachebench-standalone/wiki/HowToBuild and
http://ftp.ps.pl/pub/apache//apr/binaries/win32/apr-1.3.6-iconv-1.2.1-util-1.3.8-win32-x86-msvcrt60.zip (just not available).

Comment: The stand-alone exe complains that "libapr-1.dll" is missing.

Comment: And with a 2.2 version use the -t timelimit option

Comment: If you can't download or it's not working, please inform me instead of downvote.

Comment: Some lib is probably missing, but it is working when ab-standalone.exe is executed from apache22/bin (so it requires apache 2.2 installation).

Comment: @Dzwiedziu-nkg Hi! I wonder where can i find the version 2.4 you mentioned. I did `apt-get install apache2-utils` and it installed 2.3 by default. I hope 2.4 can save me from the agonizing.

Comment: @yeehaw what is your distro? Must be very old. 2.4 was released in 2012.

Comment: @Dzwiedziu-nkg It is a ubuntu 18.04 machine. Not sure how is Linux different...

Answer (score 20):

```
ab --help 

-s timeout      Seconds to max. wait for each response
                    Default is 30 seconds
```

Add option: **-s 120** to ab command, Where 120 is new timeout. If it is not enough set it even higher...

Answer (score 13):

ab --help

```
-s      timeout      Seconds to max. wait for each response
                    Default is 30 seconds

-k                    Use HTTP KeepAlive feature
```

It works for me

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like an ab bug.

I had a similar problem on OS X (now that you mention it happens on Windows, I feel more confident that ab is the culprit).  I went around profiling and tracing my web application, but couldn't find anything.  I then tested static pages off of nginx, and it still gave me the error.  So I then went and found a replacement... jMeter.  Works great, but I would still like to know what the ab problem is.

Comment: I'm wondering the same.  In my situation I'm using high concurrency and the failure isn't reproducible, but consistently -n minus 2.  e.g. ab -c 500 -n 10000 => 9998 complete, 2 timeout.  Maybe related: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22686

Answer (score 0):

ab doesn't work through a HTTP proxy -- it times out.
Just try instead of copy/pasing its help page.