# Apache bench Connection refused (61) apr_socket_recv

Tags: python, serversocket, apachebench

I have a similar issue with this [ab is erroring out with apr_socket_recv: Connection refused (61)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938869/ab-is-erroring-out-with-apr-socket-recv-connection-refused-61), and I have tried upgrading the new apache bench but the problem still exists. I have no idea whether the problem lies in apache bench or the server. I am using python Gevent Server with bottle framework.

Apache bench version

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1430300 $>
```

Trace error

```
Benchmarking ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
apr_socket_recv: Connection refused (61)
apr_socket_recv: Connection refused (61)
apr_socket_recv: Connection refused (61)
apr_socket_recv: Connection refused (61)

Test aborted after 10 failures

apr_socket_connect(): Operation already in progress (37)
Total of 468 requests completed
```

Comment: The same problem. Tried to increase ulimit as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578594/how-to-increase-limits-on-sockets-on-osx-for-load-testing but it doesn't help

Comment: Did you check the right ports are open on the security group of your ec2 instance ?

Comment: yeah I have set the inbound to listen to 8000 port which is the default port for the server.

Comment: Please post the answer if you managed to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Does the hostname for which you're testing with ab have an IPv6 record?  I resolved my problems by adding IPv6 configurations to my servers.  `ab http://111.222.111.222/` worked, but `ab http://subdomain.domain.com/` didn't work.  `subdomain.domain.com` had both IPv4 and IPv6 records, and I changed my configuration:

**New, Enabled IPv6 Configuration**

```
server {
  listen       [80;      #IPv4
  listen       [::]:80;  #IPv6

  server_name  localhost;    
  ...
}
```

**Original, Disabled IPv6 Configuration**

```
server {
  listen       80;

  server_name  localhost;    
  ...
}
```

More info: http://nginxlibrary.com/enable-ipv6-support/

Answer (score 0):

## seeing this after OSX 10.10.4 update or restart?

I just had this error show up after an OSX restart with system and xcode updates. After trying several things, on a hunch, I tried running xcode first and then re-tried ab. And it just worked. I was guessing if there was some interaction with command line tool terms had to be accepted as it had been in the past, but there was no such prompt. That said, after I ran xcode once, ab just worked. In case this help anyone ...