# Why is my Hello World go server getting crushed by ApacheBench?

Tags: http, go, osx-yosemite

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello world!\n")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

I've got a couple of incredibly basic HTTP servers, and all of them are exhibiting this problem.

```
$ ab -c 1000 -n 10000 http://127.0.0.1:8000/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1604373 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 5000 requests
apr_socket_recv: Connection refused (61)
Total of 5112 requests completed
```

With a smaller concurrency value, things still fall over. For me, the issue seems to show up around the 5k-6k mark usually:

```
$ ab -c 10 -n 10000 http://127.0.0.1:8000/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1604373 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
apr_socket_recv: Operation timed out (60)
Total of 6277 requests completed
```

And in fact, you can drop concurrency entirely and the problem still (sometimes) happens:

```
$ ab -c 1 -n 10000 http://127.0.0.1:8000/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1604373 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
apr_socket_recv: Operation timed out (60)
Total of 6278 requests completed
```

I can't help but wonder if I'm hitting some kind of operating system limit somewhere? How would I tell? And how would I mitigate?

Comment: `ab` isn't very good, and the Go http server far out performs it. `ab` also work very poorly on osx. You're exhausting some local resource, like available sockets.

Comment: How do you launch your server? I don't see you setting GOMAXPROCS anywhere.

Comment: I think that by default, the connection of the Go server is not closed so it can be reused, but it seems that `ab` is not reusing nor closing them fast enough so the maximum open connection is reached. You may try setting `r.Close` to `true` in your handler (I haven't actually tested it).

Comment: Using `wrk` on my laptop, your hello server reaches 46000req/sec (@Ainar-G: that's only using GOMAXPROCS=1 too. When you're network bound, a low GOMAXPROCS is often more efficient).

Comment: My money is on sockets left in TIME_WAIT state..`netstat` should reveal if that is the case.

Comment: @siritinga: That won't help, since `ab` only uses http/1.0 and wasn't invoked with keepalive. The connection *must* be closed every time.

Comment: My `netstat`-fu is not great. How would I check for `TIME_WAIT` state? I `grep`ed for `TIME_WAIT` and got nothing.

Comment: @JimB I also tried it w/ `-k` and that reduces the frequency of failures, but doesn't eliminate them.

Comment: Gave things a go w/ `httperf` and that seems not to be dropping errors, but if it goes much past 20,000 requests or so, the connection rate drops off a cliff until it's only a few connections per second instead of 10k+. Run the test w/ 10k requests or 20k, it's done in 2 seconds or less. But 30k and it never finishes.

Comment: @BobAman: tried `httperf`, and it seems to be even slower than `ab -k` on my system, but still has no problem going to 100k requests. This benchmark really is of no use, since the benchmarking tool (and the local network stack) is being tested even more than the Go server.

Comment: So I tried out `wrk` and that definitely did much better.

More interestingly, I added `req.Body.Close()` and got a measurable speed-up as well as much more stability out of both `ab` and `httperf`.

Comment: This problem doesn't come up on my Linux system (ubuntu 15.04). What OS and distro (if applicable) are you using? Perhaps @JimB's answer may be relevant to you.

Comment: This is on OS X. I've got a Vagrant-launched Kubernetes mini-cluster I'm fiddling with and I'm testing the above Hello World app both inside the cluster and running directly on the host OS. Trying to ascertain performance overhead from Kubernetes service load balancers. Obviously, the Vagrant aspect means that results will not reflect what things will look like in EC2, but I'd like to optimize what I can from my development machine first before I start tweaking things on a cluster deploy that actually costs $.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In short, you're running out of ports.

The default ephemeral port range on osx is 49152-65535, which is only 16,383 ports. Since each `ab` request is `http/1.0` (without keepalive in your first examples), each new request takes another port.

As each port is used, it get's put into a queue where it waits for the tcp "Maximum Segment Lifetime", which is configured to be 15 seconds on osx. So if you use more than 16,383 ports in 15 seconds, you're effectively going to get throttled by the OS on further connections. Depending on which process runs out of ports first, you will get connection errors from the server, or hangs from `ab`.

You can mitigate this by using an `http/1.1` capable load generator like `wrk`, or using the keepalive (`-k`) option for `ab`, so that connections are reused based on the tool's concurrency settings.

Now, the server code you're benchmarking does so little, that the load generator is being taxed just as much as the sever itself, with the local os and network stack likely making a good contribution. If you want to benchmark an http server, it's better to do some meaningful work from multiple clients not running on the same machine.

Comment: In this case, my primary objective is not to benchmark the app server, I'm really trying to get a feel for the performance overhead of an entire Kubernetes stack relative to the app server itself, but saw some confusing results I didn't understand on the way to that objective.

Comment: How would I find out how many ephemeral ports are currently left available?

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, with a virtual machine, would ephemeral ports used within a guest OS affect the host in any way? i.e., Could I spin up a bunch of VMs running `wrk`/`ab`/`httperf` to bypass the OS X ephemeral port limitation?

Comment: @BobAman: The forced delay is mostly just a limitation on osx, and the network stack and loopback device on osx is not as finely tuned as e.g. Linux. Local VMs may help provide a base for comparison, but you have to keep the same base os. Comparing an app running in a vagrant VM vs the local host is pointless. Throwing thousands of connections at a toy server doesn't prove anything. Are you trying to compare bandwidth, latency, CPU load or liveness under high concurrency? These tools are conflating all these.

Comment: Keep your control variables constant throughout your tests, and narrow down what you're looking for. Ask questions like "does running in docker cause unacceptable latency for *my* application?", or "does this load balancer affect the bandwidth of *my* application?"

Comment: I'm only looking for order-of-magnitude bottlenecks right now. i.e. What happens if I put haproxy in front of something vs. the Kubernetes load balancer in front of the same thing? And more with the purpose of finding things that are misconfigured rather than making larger architectural decisions.