# too many open files, when using net/http

Tags: http, go

I am writing REST service using [go-json-rest](https://github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest), which inturn using net/http.

My server code is simply, get the request and pass it to a channel

Here is my server code

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest/rest"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

const workerCount = 4
var evChannel = make(chan Event)
var workers = make([]*LogWorker, workerCount)
const maxLogFileSize = 100 // In MB
const maxLogFileBackups = 30
const maxLogFileAge = 5
const logFileName = "/home/sam/tmp/go_logs/event_"

func main() {
    // Initialize workers
    // Four workers is being created
    for i := 0; i < workerCount; i++ {
        var fileName = logFileName + strconv.Itoa(i)
        workers[i] = NewLogWorker(fileName, maxLogFileSize, maxLogFileBackups, maxLogFileAge)
        go workers[i].Work(evChannel)
    }    

    // Initialize REST API
    api := rest.NewApi()
    //api.Use(rest.DefaultDevStack...)
    api.Use(rest.DefaultCommonStack...)
    router, err := rest.MakeRouter(
        rest.Post("/events", StoreEvents),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    api.SetApp(router)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":4545", api.MakeHandler()))
}

func StoreEvents(w rest.ResponseWriter, r *rest.Request) {
    event := Event{}
    err := r.DecodeJsonPayload(&event)
    if err != nil {
        rest.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    // TODO : Add validation if needed
    // Add code to parse the request and add further information to event 
    // log.Println()
    select {
        case evChannel <- event:
        case <- time.After(5 * time.Second):
      // throw away the message, so sad
    }    
    // evChannel <- event
    //log.Println(Csv(event))
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```

When I execute it continuously using jmeter I am occasionally getting the below error

> http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:4545: too many open files; retrying in 10ms

Does net/http open files for every request?

Comment: Sockets, yes. You may need to increase your fd limit (via `ulimit` or `sysctl`).

Comment: [File descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), to be more specific. It can not be easily distinguished wether we have too many open files or other resources.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352725/why-is-my-hello-world-go-server-getting-crushed-by-apachebench. Also make sure jmeter is reusing http/1.1 connection properly, or use something else to generate requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting elithrar comment as answer

Sockets, yes. You may need to increase your fd limit (via ulimit or sysctl).