# Go net/http hang after constantly number of requests

Tags: web-services, networking, go

I setup a very simple and basic http server with Go `net/http` like this:

```
package main

import (
  "net/http"
  "fmt"
)

func defaultHttpPing(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  fmt.Fprint(w, "Pong")
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/ping", defaultHttpPing)
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

I believe that this is the minimal Go http server I can write and it shouldn't have any application bugs. Unfortunately, when I use `ab` to do a stress test on this server:

```
ab -n 100000 -c 100 http://localhost:8080/ping
```

It failed with this output:

```
Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 10000 requests
apr_pollset_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
Total of 16482 requests completed
```

I was so surprised because my previous `ab` tests with fewer number of requests with the same concurrency level such as `-n 10000 -c 100` are successful. I also tried more `-n 100000 -c 100` tests and it kept failing with around `16K` successful requests consistently.

What's wrong with my server? I also think that Go's `net/http` has some weird problems. Maybe, just a sense that's something to deal with memory leak.

*Additional environment info:*

OS: Mac OS, El Capitan
limits:

```
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  unlimited
-u: processes                       709
-n: file descriptors                524288
```

Comment: Does the `http.ListenAndServe` call return an error?

Comment: @mrd0ll4r, No, I can even do another test without restarting the http server.

Comment: Stop using `ab`. You're running out of ports. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352725/why-is-my-hello-world-go-server-getting-crushed-by-apachebench/30357879

Comment: Thank you @JimB, that answered my question and also blew my mind.