# Go http server slow benchmark performance

Tags: performance, http, go, webserver

I was trying to find the maximum throughput of a go webserver. I ran simplewebserver on a 8 core machine(Intel Xeon 2.5 Mhz) and ran wrk tool on a different 8 core machine. Iperf command shows around 8-10Gbps between these machines . Initially, I made a mistake by using apache ab tool that gave only 16k requests/second. The problem was same as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352725/why-is-my-hello-world-go-server-getting-crushed-by-apachebench). Now when I switched to wrk tool,  I am getting around 90k requests per second and ~ 11MB/sec.

on the first 8 core machine, I ran simplewebserver.go

```
package main

import (
   "io"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
)

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello world!")
}

 func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(8)
    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
 }
```

On a different 8 core machine, i ran

```
 ./wrk -t8 -c1000 -d10s http://10.0.0.6:8000/
```

Result:

```
Running 10s test @ http://10.0.0.6:8000/
8 threads and 1000 connections
Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
Latency    42.65ms  114.89ms   1.96s    91.33%
Req/Sec    11.54k     3.01k   25.10k    74.88%
923158 requests in 10.10s, 113.57MB read
Socket errors: connect 0, read 0, write 0, timeout 20
Requests/sec:  91415.11
Transfer/sec:     11.25MB
```

Can i say that I have reached maximum throughput of a golang web server?  I am getting 11 MB/sec which looks quite small for the basic program. If I run the wrk tool on www.google.com page, I am getting around 200 MB/sec. Even for larger complex computing systems like kafka(java server), the benchmark results get more than  70 MB/sec(https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines). How can a golang server handle extreme workloads of millions of requests per second(more than 100MB/sec minimum)? Am I wrong in any assumptions?

UPDATE:

I ran the same program on a 16 core machine with the same specs. I changed the maxprocs to 16 and results went higher to 120k requests/sec. I feel that I have the reached the maximum of golang http server and hence I am not finding any significant increment in the requests/sec.

Comment: www.google.com serves more than just "hello". Throughput and request rate are hardly related.

Comment: To elaborate on that, I'd imagine you'd get a much higher throughput if your hello world function returned the contents of a large file on disk.

Comment: @JimB Are the benchmark results that I got, nearer to theoretical maximum of golang http server ? It is only 90k results per second.  I read that java server implementation supports much more concurrent connections- http://shenfeng.me/600k-concurrent-connection-http-kit.html

Comment: @JoshWilson If you see the linkedin performance results link that I posted, they did the benchmarks with 50 million 100 byte records.  "For this first test I create a topic with six partitions and no replication. Then I produce 50 million small (100 byte) records as quickly as possible from a single thread.
The reason for focusing on small records in these tests is that it is the harder case for a messaging system (generally). It is easy to get good throughput in MB/sec if the messages are large, but much harder to get good throughput when the messages are small"

Comment: Concurrent connections and request rate are also unrelated. You seem to be targeting random benchmarks from random unrelated technologies. What is the point of all this?

Comment: @JimB I am not concerned about the concurrent connections. That is a secondary factor. My  problem is only on request rate.

Comment: I honestly don't know how well golang preforms in comparison to other languages, but you are comparing an http server to one that takes in log messages. There is probably a bit of overhead parsing the http request and encoding the response. You'll also have a little overhead on the flexibility of the framework. If you want to test pure speed, try making something  like https://coderwall.com/p/wohavg/creating-a-simple-tcp-server-in-go and then add pooling so you don't reallocate new buffers. You may never get quite to the performance of kafka, but at that would be a good comparison.

Comment: And there's a reasonable chance when you hit google.com every single one of your requests is going to a different server, so again a pretty bad comparison.

Comment: @JoshWilson can you explain bit more about pooling? What would be the best way to benchmark the server tcp performance ? I see that most of tools like iperf, needs server and client running the same tool. I couldn't find any tool to test the performance of a tcp server. (like wrk,ab for http servers)

Comment: What exactly is your use case? Rarely is network speed going to be the bottleneck.

Comment: @JoshWilson I needed a high performant server than can accept maximum number of requests per sec. I was trying to see the benchmark values of  golang http server because I was doubtful of the overhead added due to the language implementation.  Having 100k req/sec was not very impressive.

Comment: so you're going to accept the connections and then just drop them on the floor?

Comment: @JoshWilson You can see the light weight java server https://www.techempower.com/blog/2014/03/04/one-million-http-rps-without-load-balancing-is-easy/ can give around 1M http request per second while in golang, i am just getting around 1/10th(100k requests per second) for almost same kind of setup. Hence I was wondering if I am missing out something or is it the maximum that I can achieve in golang http implementation

Comment: did you run that java server in the same setup or are you taking their numbers, because that is useless. If you want some kind of real comparison you should run that java server on the same box as the golang one and test that.

Comment: also your latency is ridiculously high. I suspect more a problem with your testbox or network here. I have a nginx/uwsgi/django server runnning doing real work at <20ms, so i think you are really testing network latency here.

Comment: @RickyA  I also noticed the latency value. I am not sure how to debug this issue.  Iperf command between these machines  show 8-10 Gbps. Hence, I have less suspicion on the network. Any other ideas?

Comment: Latency is not bandwidth. In fact the only correlation is that when you consume all your bandwidth, your latency will rise. Latency normally stems from other things like the type of networking (wireless == crap) topology of network, load on the servers themself (not io). I really cannot tell you something meaningful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Golang net/http is rather slow. If the goal is to maximize the requests rate there are other implementations. For example https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp In my tests fasthttp doubles the query rate. My test is a short request and short reply.

The library comes with limitations, like no HTTP/2 support. If you need HTTP for REST API and you are not looking for interoperability fasthttp will fit nicely

Answer (score 3):

"premature optimization is the root of all evil"[1](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

I would suggest building something for your use case and then attempting to optimize. It is difficult to build a good benchmark that tests what you want so make sure you are testing what you want and not something like the speed of your router.