# Go httputil.ReverseProxy connection reset by peer

Tags: http, go, proxy

I have the task to make a reverse proxy app which extracts some specific info from request/response body and send it into logstash. So i decided to do some load testing first. I wrote very simple backend web server and basic proxy.

*Backend server code:*

```
package main

import "net/http"

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3001", nil)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.Body.Close()
    w.Write([]byte("test"))
}
```

*Reverse proxy server code:*

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
)

var (
    proxy *httputil.ReverseProxy
)

func init() {
    url, _ := url.Parse("http://localhost:3001")
    proxy = httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(url)
    proxy.Transport = &mimTransport{}
}

func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", proxy)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.Host = "localhost:3001"
    proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

type mimTransport struct {
}

func (t *mimTransport) RoundTrip(request *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    response, err := http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(request)
    if response != nil {
        defer request.Body.Close()
    }

    // info extraction will be here

    return response, err
}
```

As you can see backend server listening `localhost:3001` and proxy listening `localhost:3000`

I'am using apache benchmark for load testing.

When i running `$ ab -c 20 -n 20000 -s 10 http://127.0.0.1:3000/` around 12k-14k requests proxy start writing errors like:

```
2016/12/23 13:02:50 http: proxy error: read tcp [::1]:58330->[::1]:3001: read: connection reset by peer
2016/12/23 13:02:50 http: proxy error: read tcp [::1]:58461->[::1]:3001: read: connection reset by peer
2016/12/23 13:02:50 http: proxy error: read tcp [::1]:58977->[::1]:3001: read: connection reset by peer
2016/12/23 13:02:50 http: proxy error: read tcp [::1]:59459->[::1]:3001: read: connection reset by peer
...
```

and soon after that apache bench dies by timeout. Some bench results:

```
Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 8000 requests
Completed 10000 requests
^C

Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            3000

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        4 bytes

Concurrency Level:      20
Time taken for tests:   4.868 seconds
Complete requests:      11514
Failed requests:        22
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 22, Exceptions: 0)
Non-2xx responses:      22
Total transferred:      1381790 bytes
HTML transferred:       45968 bytes
Requests per second:    2365.28 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       8.456 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.423 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          277.20 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    1   4.2      1     111
Processing:     0    3   4.8      3     113
Waiting:        0    3   4.7      3     113
Total:          0    4   6.4      4     116

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      4
  66%      4
  75%      5
  80%      5
  90%      5
  95%      6
  98%      6
  99%      7
 100%    116 (longest request)
```

There is more, if i start `ab` again right after the end of first test, i'll receive something like:

```
Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
apr_pollset_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
Total of 52 requests completed
```

(Maybe some connection from previous test still alive)

Internet says there is some DoS protection mechanism in Go, and apparently it is cause of reseted connections. 
So my questions is:

1. Why it reset connections (read buffer is full, timeout is happens, too many connections or maybe my code is broken)
2. Can i tweak this mechanism? For example extend buffer of change max timeout.
3. Some hints how correctly handle this type of errors.

Thanks.

Comment: `ab` is using http/1.0 without keepalive. Don't use `ab`.

Comment: ab is not your best choice. Have a look at wrk which is like ab but better in so many ways or vegeta (https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta)

Comment: Maybe it not best, and i definitely will try other solutions (thanks for it), but i can't guarantee that this problem won't occur in production. So i want to now how to fix/debug it.

Comment: @MarkBelotskiy: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774624/go-http-get-concurrency-and-connection-reset-by-peer/37813844#37813844, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352725/why-is-my-hello-world-go-server-getting-crushed-by-apachebench/30357879#30357879 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813587/go-client-program-generates-a-lot-a-sockets-in-time-wait-state/39834253#39834253

Comment: @JimB So it either OS limit or http.Transport limit... thanks for hints. I'll  try both and report.

Comment: I have tried to change both  net.inet.tcp.msl system parameter and MaxIdleConnsPerHost (this way`proxy.Transport = &mimTransport{MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 10}`) it seems have no effect on `connection reset by peer` error. I also switched to vegeta, and it gives me much better results. But error still occurs when i set keepalive to false (real http requests usually do not use keepalive).